# Odoo / owl.js pass properties to parent component in a loop

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

This is a beginner question, but can't figure out where mistake is, likely syntax.

I try to render array of objects and pass props to child component.
The child components are being rendered on the page, but this.props.element in child component is `null`

So, parent component template is
service_table_view.xml

```
<t t-foreach="state.elements" t-as='el'>
     <TableElement element="el" />
</t>
```

service_table_view.js

```
import {TableElement} from "../service_table_element/service_table_element";

const {Component} = owl;
const {useState} = owl.hooks;

export class TableView extends Component {

    /**
     * @override
     */
    setup() {
        super.setup();

        const elements = [
           
            {
                id: 1,
                type: 'lift',
                isBusy: false,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                type: 'lift',
                isBusy: false,
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                type: 'alignment',
                isBusy: false,
            },
          
        ]
this.state = useState({elements})

    }


}

Object.assign(TableView, {
    template: 'service.TableView',
    components: {TableElement}
});
```

The child component
service_table_element.js

```
export class TableElement extends Component {

    /**
     * @override
     */
    setup() {
        console.log('TABLE ELEMENT', this.props.element); <---- null
        super.setup();


        this.state = useState({
            showDialog: false,
            isBusy: false,
        });
    }
}
Object.assign(TableElement, {
    props: {
        element: {type: Array, element: Object}
    },
    template: 'service.TableElement',
});
```

Either in child template "service_table_element.xml" when I try to call `<t t-esc="props.element.id"/>` error is occured, because props.element is null

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust the state assignment to correct this.

```
this.state = useState({elements: elements})
console.log('TABLE ELEMENT', this.props.elements);
```

Comment: No, this is the same. In fact, it is written like {elements: elements} in my code, I just simplified it in the question above. Same no result, anyway.

Comment: did you change the console to console.log('Elements in TableView:', this.state.elements);
instead of  this.state.element ?

Comment: I need to receive data from props, so I log this.props
If I log this.state, the data from local state is correct

Comment: Could you please share the updated console statement here ?